# What is the latest version for MonoDevelop that support mono 2.10.11 in Mac?

Tags: mono, monodevelop

MonoDevelop 4.2.2 needs higher mono version, but I need mono 2.10.11, what is the latest version I should use?

Thanks

Comment: why do you need such an old version of mono?

Comment: Because I tried to replace the IDE in Unity3D, after some searching, I knew it is better to use the Unity bundled version.